# How to check existence of element by id using Mootools

Tags: mootools

How to check existence of element by id  using Mootools

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### html:

```
<div id="foo">some content</div>
```

#### javascript

```
var foo = document.id('foo'); // or $ but should be avoided due to conflicts

// if it returns an Element object, it will be truthy.
if (foo) {
    // code for when it exists
}
else {
    // code for when it does not.
}
```

incidentally, this mimics the behaviour of the return value of `document.getElementById` which is vanilla js. it can be true for any selector that is meant to return a single Element, like `document.getElement('div.login > a.active')` - does not need to be by ID only.